# Swipe to delete doesn't work with Timer

Tags: swift

I have implement the option "Swipe to delete" in my TableView like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
  return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
 UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .delete {
    rows.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    runnerTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    runnerTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

It works fine before the implementation of my Timer:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, 
 selector:#selector(ViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

func updateTimer () {
  var j = 0
  for _ in rows {
    if (rows[j]["Playing"] as! Bool == true ) {
      rows[j]["time"] = (rows[j]["time"] as! Double + 0.01) as AnyObject
    }
    j += 1
  }
  runnerTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Now, the swipe to delete just doesn't work. Nothing append when I swipe.

How can I do it works again?

Comment: 1. I copy your code, it works. 

2. I implement your timer, it works.

What did you in your `updateTimer`?

Comment: You should not keep reload your `tableview`!

Comment: @Codus in the updateTimer's function?

Comment: yes! updateTimer's's interval too short and your datasource did not changed.

Comment: yes i'm going to update view every 0.03 seconds and Try

Comment: there is a better way to archeve your goal. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

1. remove `reloadData` in `updateTimer`
2. use my code to display your `rows[j]["time"]`.

[image: My workable way]

**Origin**

If you want to show your timer, you can use this:

```
func updateTimer() {
    var j = 0
    for _ in rows {
        if (rows[j]["Playing"] as! Bool == true ) {
            rows[j]["time"] = (rows[j]["time"] as! Double + 0.01) as AnyObject
        }
        j += 1
    }

    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            cell.timeLabel.text = "\(rows[indexPath.row]["time"])"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show my timer, that's already done, I'm trying to do a gif for show the problem

Comment: If you don't want to show your timer, it is not necessary to `reloadData` after `rows[j]["time"]` changed

Comment: it's already done, I show it ! but I can try your method for show

Comment: Hope to help :)